# Workflow question

Tags: workflow

I created a workflow in sp designer, it generated 2 forms, then I associted the workflow to a content type and it opens a browser when I selected the user I got this error

Its important to note there is that I had done this, but I deleted the workflow from the content type because I just wanted to be sure that I learnt the process.

There is already a workflow association with this name 'Trainin gApproval WorkFlow'.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: There is already a workflow association with this name 'Trainin gApproval WorkFlow'.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Comment: This hasnt worked yet, I still have this error.

There is already a workflow association with this name 'Trainin gApproval WorkFlow'.

Comment: I have same issue, when trying to use contentType.WorkflowAssociations.Update(wfAssociation);.  

I followed instructions here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spcontenttype.workflowassociations.aspx.

Was there resolution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are again exercising the entire steps of creating a workflow and adding it again to a content type, then I would suggest you to retarct the one you developed previously from the Solutions Gallery in your site collection first and then proceed with this.

Comment: how can I do that?

Comment: At the root of your site collection, go to site settngs page and look for *Solutions Gallery* link. Now find your workflow solution in there, select it and choose to deactivate and remove it from the ribbnon.

Comment: the workflow is not there, I used SPD to create the workflow not Visual Studio.

Comment: What kind of workflow is that? Is that a reusable WF created in SPD2010. If it is then you must see a WSP for your workflow in the solutions gallery...